# Google Data studio-Visualisation Error

Tags: looker-studio

I have created a Dashboard using Google Data studio. But In one dashboard whenever I pass my filter selection ,there is error in the dashboard (scorecard,table)as shown in below image. As soon as I click on refresh data ,data loads perfectly.
[image]

What's the issue here ?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score -1):

It's likely due to the pivot element taking up a lot of the processing power, and the scorecards error. Putting the pivot table on a separate page should fix this.